# How to swap values of an array? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) and I am trying to create a polyline and marker points but it gives opposite lat and long so I have to swap them. Creating a marker is easy because it only has one pair of lat and long but creating a polyline is complicated because has a lot of points.
Below is what I am currently using to swap lat and long for marker points.

```
var splitObj = objVal.toString().split("],[");
var latlng = splitObj.map(function(x)
    {
        var couple= (/\d+.\d+, \d+.\d+/g).exec(x).toString();
        var splitted = couple.split(", ");
        return "["+splitted[1]+","+splitted[0]+"]";
    });
latlng.join();
```

Result:

> ['[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]'] // this is the objVal
> expectation:
> ['[[b,a], [d,c], [f,e]]']
> reality:
> ['[b,a]']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is a string of nested-array-like values, the below solution may help in transforming/swapping latitude-longitude values.

Code Snippet

```js
const inpVal = ['[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]'];

// helper method to strip first & last char of a string
const stripFirstLast = s => s.slice(1, s.length - 1);

// helper method to swap lat & longitutde values
const swapLatLon = ([lat, lon]) => [lon, lat];

// place holder to safe-keep value of input
const tmp = stripFirstLast(inpVal[0])
  .replaceAll('], ', '] | ')
  .split(' | ');

// calculate the result
const res = ["[" +
  tmp.map(
    x => '[' +
    swapLatLon(
      stripFirstLast(x).split(', ')
    ).join(', ') +
    ']'
  ).join(', ') +
  "]"
];

// console-log to validate/verify
console.log(
  'input: ', inpVal,
  '\nresult: ', res
);
```

**Explanation**

Comments inline explain the approach used.

**Swap with actual values (and not string)**

> This is an almost-exact replica of [Andy's
> solution/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71581810/13658816) with
> only one change instead of handling the inner array as `arr`, the
> iterator directly accesses the lat & lon values. I think it makes the
> solution a little more easier to read.

```js
// Previous solution where the orig data was not taken as a string
const swapLoLa = arr => arr.map(([lon, lat]) => [lat, lon]);
const orig = [[124.432841, 8.3963], [124.496898, 8.3963], [124.571937, 8.40898]];
console.log(
  'orig arr: ', orig,
  '\nswapped arr: ', swapLoLa(orig)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

`map` over the array it and, for each inner array, return a new array after swapping the elements around.

```js
const data = [[124.432841, 8.3963], [124.496898, 8.3963], [124.571937, 8.40898]];

const result = data.map(arr => {
  return [arr[1], arr[0]];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Even simpler like so: `const result = data.map(([la, lo]) => ([lo, la]));`.

Comment: On second thought, I think in OP's question the `data` array is like so: `const data = ['[124.432841, 8.3963], [124.496898, 8.3963], [124.571937, 8.40898]']`. The whole inner-array is within quotes. So, it shows-up as a string & not an array.

Comment: the results are [Array(2)]
 0: Array(2)
     0: "["
     1: "["
     length: 2

Comment: To use this solution/method you need to pass it a nested-array of latitude, longitude values. Such as: `[[124.432841, 8.3963], [124.496898, 8.3963], [124.571937, 8.40898]]` <-- this is a nested array where the inner array are lat-long values. What exactly is your input - is it like the one above or is it like this: `['[[124.432841, 8.3963], [124.496898, 8.3963], [124.571937, 8.40898]]']`. This is an array of just one element and that element is a `string`.

Comment: @JaneDoe a) why is your leaflet lat/lng data represented by an array of strings, and b) why would you want to convert an array of lat/lngs back into strings?

Comment: @Andy I thought that was the best way to split them lol

Comment: Is that an actual array, is it JSON? @JaneDoe. If it's JSON how are you parsing it? Your update makes less sense now because `a` and `b` are referring to variables, and not actual numbers.